# Compounding frequency for Recurring Deposit account at ICICI Bank?

Tags: banking, interest-rate, india

Does anyone know the frequency of compounding of a Recurring Deposit account at ICICI Bank? It isn't mentioned anywhere in their website and looks like they are conveniently hiding the fact.

Answer (score 2):

Typically the compounding of Interest is on yearly Basis. The best way to verify this is call up the help desk or walk into branch.

Answer (score 0):

Their FDs compound quarterly, so should the RDs. But like Dheer said, call them up.

Answer (score 0):

It might be half yearly I guess, which is their interest crediting period. If you have online banking and if you look at your RD statement you can find that. In every six months they will credit the interest and they will add interest to that as well in the final amount. This is my observation but still you can confirm it from the bank.